# Nutch Parse out HTML5 header tag

Tags: solr, nutch

I am trying to parse HTML5 pages using Nutch 1.2 and running into problems with the HTML5 tag 'header' being included in the index.

I used to exclude the HTML4 header with 'parser.html.divIDsToExclude' but this will no longer meet my requirements.

Is there a similar plugin which can exclude configured HTML5 tags

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used this plugin successfully with Nutch 1.6.

[Nutch filter xpath](http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/)

I did have the reverse requirement, I wanted to only include a specific div. :)

With this plugin you can configure which sections of the HTML document you want to extract, using XPath queries.